# How to hide “Siri app suggestions” in iOS?

Tags: ios, siri

When you swipe down on the homescreen, iOS 9 now displays a row of app suggestions below the Search field. Is it possible to hide this row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Settings > General > Spotlight Search and you'll see a switch for Siri Suggestions at the top of the screen.[image]